# Find the next section by class name

Tags: jquery, html

How can I show the next div with class `form_section` by clicking `.btn_next`?

```js
$(".form_section").hide();

$(document).on("click", ".btn_next", function(e) {
  $(this).next(".form_section").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row form_section">
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn_next">SHOW NEXT SECTION</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form_section">
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn_next">SHOW NEXT SECTION</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form_section">
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn_next">SHOW NEXT SECTION</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to hide current "`.form_section`" section (to the button which was clicked), then get the next `.form_section` to show.

```
<script>

        //$(".form_section").hide();
        $(document).on("click", ".btn_next", function(e){
            $(this).parents('.form_section').hide();
            $(this).parents('.form_section').next().show();                
        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Please consider leaving an explanation about why your answer solves the problem and maybe what was wrong with the OP's attempt.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen just tried to explain a little. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to traverse the DOM to retrieve the nearest parent `.form_section` to the button which was clicked, hide it, then get the next `.form_section` to show.

To do that you can use a combination of `closest()`, `hide()`, `next()` and `show()`. Try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".btn_next", function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.form_section').hide().next(".form_section").show();
});
```

```css
.form_section { display: none; }
.form_section:nth-of-type(1) { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row form_section">
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn_next">SHOW NEXT SECTION</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form_section">
  <div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn_next">SHOW NEXT SECTION</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form_section">
  <div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn_next">SHOW NEXT SECTION</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the use of CSS to hide/show the relevant elements when the page loads. This is a better approach than using JS as it avoids the [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).